Optimizing Query Performance for Large Tables in SQL Server Using Dapper ORM
Introduction:
In our application, we're utilizing the Dapper ORM to interact with a SQL Server database. One of our critical tables, OperationSteps, has grown significantly over time, leading to performance issues, particularly during query execution. This post aims to explore strategies for optimizing query performance for large tables in SQL Server while using Dapper ORM.
Table Definition:
Let's start by examining the structure of the GameSessions table:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OperationSteps](
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OperationName] [nvarchar](300) NOT NULL,
    [FatherName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [EventType] [nvarchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [StepId] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [TransactionId] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [Amount] [float] NOT NULL,
    [TimeStamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [OperationIdExternal] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [TaxesAmount] [decimal](19, 4) NULL,
    [Round] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [FatherId] [smallint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_OperationSteps] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [UserId] ASC,
    [TransactionId] ASC,
    [StepsId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

Columns included in all the select statements
SELECT
    UserId,
    OperationName,
    OperationIdExternal AS GameId,
    ProviderId,
    ProviderName,
    EventType,
    StepId,
    TransactionId,
    Amount,
    TimeStamp,
    TaxesAmount,
    Round

Query Where Clause
In our queries we use the following where clauses :


WHERE [ProviderId] = @ProviderId
       AND [OperationIdExternal] = @GameId
       AND [Round] = @Round
       AND [EventType] = @EventType



 WHERE [ProviderId] = @ProviderId
       AND (@TransactionId IS NULL OR [TransactionId] = @TransactionId)
       AND (@Round IS NULL OR [Round] = @Round)
       AND (@EventType IS NULL OR [EventType] = @EventType)
       AND (@OperationId IS NULL OR [OperationIdExternal] = @OperationId)

on code side I have ( only a piece ) :
FROM dbo.OperationsSteps 
WHERE ProviderId = @ProviderId";

var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
parameters.Add("@ProviderId", providerId, DbType.Int16, ParameterDirection.Input);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(transactionId))
{
    query += " AND TransactionId = @TransactionId";
    parameters.Add("@TransactionId", transactionId, DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input);
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(round))
{
    query += " AND Round = @Round";
    parameters.Add("@Round", round, DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input);
}



WHERE [SessionId] = @SessionId
  AND [Round] = @Round
  AND [EventType] = @EventType



Numbers of record
This table has a significant number of records, ranging from 5,000,000 to 15,000,000.
I tried to apply the following changes to the structure of the table :
ALTER TABLE dbo.OperationSteps
ALTER COLUMN Round nvarchar(100);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_OperationSteps_Operation_Round_EventType
ON dbo.OperationSessions (StepId, Round, EventType);

but the query wents in timeout and lock the table.
Summary:
I'm encountering performance issues with queries executed on a large table containing millions of records in a SQL Server database. Despite utilizing Dapper for database interactions, the queries are taking 2-3 seconds to execute due to index scans. I'm seeking advice on improving query performance without disrupting the application's availability.
I'd appreciate any suggestions or insights on optimizing the query performance while the application remains online.

The WHERE is only part of the query. What are you also SELECTing? If you have an INDEX on OperationId, Round, and EventType but want to return data for columns like StepsId and TaxesAmount for 1,000's (or many more) rows, then your INDEX isn't going to be helpful as it's not covering.

Why did you ALTER the column to be an nvarchar(100)? You initially define it as a float (also probably the wrong data type), but if it's now an nvarchar that implies it's not numerical data at all.

ProviderId seems to be missing from your table. also you mention OperationSteps and GameSessions, which one is it?

Btw, unless you're on enterprise sql server version, you won't be able to create indexes without locking tables, so you'll have to bite that bullet

OK, so you are SELECTing other columns. How many rows are you expecting for your WHERE clause? 5? 500? 50,000? Can you Paste the Plan?

For "WHERE 2", you have what looks to be a "Kitchen sink"/"Catch-all" query; these easily suffer from parameter sniffing. With clauses like that, it's normally advised to stick a RECOMPILE in your OPTION clause. Otherwise you should be building the WHERE so that when a parameter has a NULL value, that particular clause in the WHERE is omitted, and when it's not, just YourColumn = @YourParameter is provided.

@ThomA Since I call the query with a SingleorDefault or FirstOrDefault the answer is very simple. 0 or 1 row :) Do you still need the execution plan?

Filtering in the application to the first row won't help if SQL Server finds, or expects to find, many rows, @user24275375 . WHERE 2 would return every row in your table if all the parameters are NULL, even if you then filter to the first row in your application afterwards.

@ThomA Parameters are always NOT NULL. Which of the 3 query I've to choose to pass you the executionPlan?

" Parameters are always NOT NULL." Then why do you have syntax like AND (@TransactionId IS NULL OR [TransactionId] = @TransactionId)? If @TransactionId can never be NULL, why do you explicit cater for when it can be?

Just curious why you chose to go with a heap for that table? You may have a reason but just in case, see "When not to use a heap" --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/heaps-tables-without-clustered-indexes?view=sql-server-ver16

@ThomA I put in the question a piece of code.

Performance questions always need the execution plan, because the query tells you nothing about how the engine obtains the data

I see this index:
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_OperationSteps_Operation_Round_EventType
ON dbo.OperationSessions (StepId, Round, EventType);

But it doesn't match any of the WHERE clause options at all. Try making ProviderID the first column in that index instead of StepID. You can optionally add an INCLUDE directive with the index for the other columns in the query, which will allow the database to entirely serve the query from the index alone. However, depending on your workload this can add more cost than you get benefit, so you'll want to test it carefully.
Then you may want to also add another unclustered index for (SessionID, Round, EventType)

Thanks a lot for your reply. the index is on (StepId,Round,EventType) ryt?
My question is : when I create it I got a timeout on the server? Is it better to apply it offile or there is a mode to applyit online without risks ?
With this index i solve issue in all my 3 Select ?

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_OperationSteps_Operation_Round_EventType
ON dbo.OperationSessions (ProviderId, Round, EventType);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_OperationSteps_Operation_Round_EventType
ON dbo.OperationSessions (StepId, Round, EventType);
ryt? My question is : when I create it I got a timeout on the server? Is it better to apply it offile or there is a mode to applyit online without risks ? With this index i solve issue in all my 3 Select ?
StepId = SessionId.
